# Return DWORD from c++ to c# (DllImport)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, dllimport

I have a c++ function like,

```
extern "C" __declspec ( dllexport ) DWORD GetSizeAfterMergeISOTemplates(BYTE* StoredISOTemplate, BYTE* CapturedISOTemplate)
{
}
```

I would like to return the size of array after merging the two byte arrays in the argument. The c++ part is working and its returning the correct value.

But my problem is I need to get the value in DWORD in c#. The function is,

```
   [DllImport("XFPLibISO")]
        extern static UInt32 GetSizeAfterMergeISOTemplates(Byte[] StoredISOTemplate, Byte[] CapturedISOTemplate);
```

But its returning the wrong value. Its 3477800 something. But actual value is around 964.

Can anybody suggest how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ function you provided means [CallingConvention.Cdecl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx). You must specify it, when applying `DllImportAttribute`:

```
[DllImport("XFPLibISO", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```